# Webpack 4 / Babel 2 functions not working in IE11

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am new to Webpack / Babel.

I hope I will be able to put together a reasonable question about this, so forgive me if the question is a bit off or I don't manage to present all the necessary details.

I am just playing around with webpack and babel in order to get familiar with the two.

My goal is to make some es6 js to work in IE 11.

The stack looks like this:

```
"webpack": "^4.14.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
```

Webpack config rules for js files:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {loader: 'babel-loader'}
}
```

Babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "ie >= 11"
          ]
        },
        "debug": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Entry js file:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
require('./index.html');
require('./scss/my.scss');
require('./js/my.js');
```

Everything is working, I have no compile errors, the compiled assets work as expected and 100% in Chrome and Firefox but in IE11 almost everything works.

Now in my.js file I have the following functions for shading colors and getting a computed style property value:

```
function shadeRGBColor(color, percent) {
    let f = color.split(',');
    let t = percent < 0 ? 0: 255;
    let p = percent < 0 ? percent*-1 : percent;
    let R = parseInt(f[0].slice(4));
    let G = parseInt(f[1]);
    let B = parseInt(f[2]);

    return "rgb("+(Math.round((t-R)*p)+R)+","+(Math.round((t-G)*p)+G)+","+(Math.round((t-B)*p)+B)+")";
}

function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
    if (el.currentStyle) return el.currentStyle[styleProp];

    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)[styleProp];
}
```

An example usage of the functions looks like this:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const containerBackgroundColor = getStyle(container, 'backgroundColor');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
box.style.backgroundColor = shadeRGBColor(containerBackgroundColor, 0.2);
```

I don't know what exactly it is but this code doesn't work in IE11 after compiling/transpiling.

What I also find interesting is that my compiled js has some standard looking webpack code but all my js code is just inside an eval() function as huge string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the problem was my function getStyle().

```
function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
    if (el.currentStyle) return el.currentStyle[styleProp];

    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)[styleProp];
}
```

The function returns rgb color in Chrome/Firefox but hex color in IE.
So when the color gets to the shadeRGBColor() in IE it's hex color so the problem is obvious from shadeRGBColor() name itself.

The solution for me was to write two new functions:

```
function isRGBColor(color) {
    return color.includes('rgb');
}

function convertHexToRGB(hexColor) {
    let hex = hexColor.replace('#','');

    let r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
    let g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
    let b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

    return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
}
```

That solved the issue for me.